# How to get started with MySQL on Mac

Tags: terminal, snow-leopard, mysql

I'm all very new to mySQL. I've installed it from the Oracle website, and I think I managed to run the server with the command:

```
sudo ./mysqld_safe --console
```

But it's impossible to open the client and have the "mysql>" prompt that nobody else seems to have a hard time having. I tried:

- `./mysql`
- `./mysql -u root -p`
- `./mysql -u root -p root`
- `./mysql -u myusername`

etc...(I also tried with 'sudo' first)

I always get the same message:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: XX)
```

As you see, I don't really know what I'm doing. Any tips?

Comment: Given this is more about MySQL than Mac, try asking over on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ – they specialise on database set up and administration. Hopefully someone there will be better able to help identify this error message.

Answer (score 3):

## Post Install Set-up

Have you been through the [post installation set up](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/postinstallation.html)?

In particular, [Securing the Initial MySQL Accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html) is important because it sets up the default users and passwords.

### brew

You may want to try installing MySQL via the [homebrew project](http://brew.sh). With `brew` installed, you can install MySQL using the command:

```
brew install mysql
```

### MAMP

Alternatively, [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) offers an application based edition of MySQL. Launching the application starts a preconfigured copy of MySQL for you – and it includes the web-based [myphpadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net).

With regard to your comment wanting a free solution, MAMP is free:

> Similar to a Linux-Distribution, **MAMP is a combination of free software and thus it is offered free of charge.** MAMP is released under the GNU General Public License and may thereby be distributed freely within the boundaries of this license.

Comment: Ok thanks, I did not see that one. I went through it and tried, as they say, to type "./mysql -u root" but still got the same error msg. Actually it's weird, because it's written that I should type "mysql ..." (without the "./") but that does not work ("command not found")

Comment: I also tried with brew: After installation, I could run the "mysql -uroot" command, as they suggest, and still got the same error msg...

Comment: Actually I still got this error msg even if the server is not running. I have no idea what to do...

Comment: Have you tried [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/)?

Comment: I am looking for a free solution

Comment: MAMP is free. I have updated the answer to include MAMP's free licensing statement.

Answer (score 0):

See what the path is to MySQL and make sure there isn't another installation conflicting with the one installed by composer. In terminal:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

You might see something like:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

You can reset the root password once you know where to call mysql from:

```
/path/to/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root password [yourpasswordhere]
```

My path to MySQL is /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin

What Operating system are you running? I used to use MAMP but I didn't care for it. I prefer to set up my own LAMP stack (Linux, Apache, MySQl, PHP) using the details outlined in this tutorial:

https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/